# SOLVED : why Django admin list is not updating the edit from the frontend React js form?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, use-effect

i am trying to make a CRUD app in DRF-Reactjs by following [Tania rascia's example](https://www.taniarascia.com/crud-app-in-react-with-hooks/)

i have successfully implemented add, delete, list view. but i am trying to edit  a specific row which is not updating in DRF backend. but the edited row is shown in the frontend list. why it is not updating in django admin list?

in DRF side views.py:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def TodoUpdate(request, pk):
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TodoSerializer(instance=todo, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

i am using cors header to interface between frontend to backend. here is the frontend code for edit:

App.js:

```
import React,{Fragment, useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import EditList from './components/EditList';
import axios from 'axios'
     
export default function App() {
  const initialTodoSate = { id: null, title: "", body: "" };
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todoList, setTodolist] = useState(initialTodoSate);
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/todo-list",{})
    .then(res=>{
      setTodos(res.data)
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  },[]) 
  
   const addTodoList = (todo) => {

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:8000/api/todo-create/",todo)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
       todo.id = todos.length + 1;
        setTodos([todo, ...todos]); 
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    setEditing(false);
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:8000/api/todo-delete/${id}/`)
    .then(res=>{
      setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  };

 const updateTodo = ( id,updatedTodo) => {
   axios
     .post(`http://localhost:8000/api/todo-update/${id}/`, id)
     .then((res) => {
       console.log(res.data);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
     });
   setEditing(false);
   setTodos(todos.map((todo) => (todo.id === id ? updatedTodo : todo)));
 };

  const editRow = (todo) => {
    setEditing(true);

    setTodolist({
      id: todo.id,
      title: todo.title,
      description: todo.description,
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Django-based Todo with React Hooks</h1>
      {editing ? (
        <Fragment>
          <h3>Edit Task</h3>
          <EditList
            editing={editing}
            setEditing={setEditing}
            todoList={todoList}
            updateTodo={updateTodo}
          />
        </Fragment>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <CreateTodo addTodoList={addTodoList} />
          <hr />
        </Fragment>
      )}
      <div className="flex-row">
        <div className="flex-large">
          <TodoList todos={todos} editRow={editRow} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and EditList.js:

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from "react";

export default function EditList({ todoList, setEditing, updateTodo }) {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([todoList]);
  useEffect(() => {
        setTodo(todoList);
  }, [todoList]);
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setTodo({ ...todo, [name]: value });
  };
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        updateTodo(todo.id, todo);
      }}
    >
      <label>Title:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="title"
        value={todo.title}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Description:</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        name="body"
        value={todo.body}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br />
      <button>Update Task</button>
      <button onClick={() => setEditing(false)} className="button muted-button">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

when i try to edit one row with title and body, it is edited and after pressing the update button, the updated row included in the list. but the problem is when i look into the django admin it has not been updated and when i check the development tools, i found an error:

*Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
at input
at form
at EditList (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:511:3)
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:70:83)
console. @ vendors~main.chunk.js:31671*

where am i having the mistake?

can anyone help me please? please let me know if you need any additional codes or information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Trying to update something should be done in a put request, not a post request. This is a REST API convention, but a discrepancy may have some consequence down the line.
2. In this case, the error in your development tools is telling you that one of your components has an onChange/onSubmit etc property that is changing over the course of one mount from null to a function. This is not what's causing your issue, but I suspect it can be fixed by declaring the code in a handleSubmit function and then putting that into your onSubmit.
3. I think the error that's actually causing your problem is that the updatedTodo is not being sent to the backend. All that is being sent is the id (second parameter of axios.post). So if you pause the backend during execution, you would see that request.data = the id only, when it should be TodoSerializer's readable fields.

PS:

1. You can add a "debugger;" statement in the code after the updateToDo async request error to see what the error actually is (read more on the development tools debugging - browser dependent).
2. Don't abuse fragments - in this case, it would make for a more accessibility-friendly experience if you use divs in most of these components. Wouldn't it make more sense if the heading of some content was grouped with the content? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/dom-order-matters

Comment: i followed your number 1, number and PS number 2. and it works like train... thanx buddy. and sorry for the late reply. when you answered the question, i was at sleep. it was a midnight over here.